# What is the difference between getActive() and getActiveSpreadsheet() in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Whats the difference between these two methods from class SpreadSheetApp in Google Apps Script?

Both return "currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none". Whats the difference between them, exactly? When should I use each one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me they're quite interchangeable really. Both return Spreadsheet object and has access to methods available to [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet). Feel free to use whichever you prefer.

Same results:

```
 Logger.log("getActiveSpreadSheet() "+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl());
 Logger.log("getActive() "+ SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl() );
```

Comment: I tested in the Script Editor with `SpreadsheetApp.getActive() === SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`, and the answer was `false`, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

They don't seem to return a pointer to the same animal.
I don't know why (don't have time to investigate) but

1. The sheet returned by `getActiveSheet()` **has** the `getRangeByName()` method - and the one from `getActive()` **doesn't** have it
2. The sheet returned by `getActiveSheet()` **doesn't have** the `getCharts()` method - and the one from `getActive()` **does** have it

Either something really over my head makes this justifiable or it is just dismal language/syntax design (maybe some legacy crap that never got resolved?)

Comment: Strange, it's other way around for me - object returned by `getActiveSheet()` **has** `getCharts()`, but **doesn't have** `getRangeByName()`. The object is actually of a class [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), not [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) (as returned by `getActive()` or `getActiveSpreadsheet()`). Besides, the question in OP wasn't about `getActiveSheet()` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this article](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/193694296/what-is-the-difference-between-getactive-and-getactivespreadsheet?hl=en), function `getActiveSpreadsheet()` is deprecated.

So it's better to use function `getActive()`.